# post message to a remote JMS provider

Tags: java, jboss, jms

I want to be able to send messages to a remote JBoss server (JBoss MQ).

I can do it for a local one but i'm stuck when trying with a remote one.

can anyone explain to me how to do it ?
are there any specific steps to take ?

[what i've tried so far]

I need to send a message to a remote server's queue (running "JBoss MQ") so that it can process the message and act on it.

```
    Properties properties = new Properties();
    properties.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContextFactory");
    properties.put(Context.URL_PKG_PREFIXES, "org.jnp.interfaces");
    properties.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "jnp://192.168.131.129:1299");
    InitialContext jndiContext = new InitialContext(properties);

    //[2] Look up connection factory and queue.
    ConnectionFactory connectionFactory = (ConnectionFactory)jndiContext.lookup("UIL2XAConnectionFactory");
    Queue queue = (Queue)jndiContext.lookup("Queue/DataTransferQueue");
```

but I get an exception when running the above code :
(even though, I can ping the remote server).

```
javax.naming.CommunicationException: Could not obtain connection to any of these urls: 192.168.1.131.129:1299 and 
discovery failed with error: javax.naming.CommunicationException: 
Receive timed out [Root exception is java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Receive timed out] 
[Root exception is javax.naming.CommunicationException: Failed to connect to server 192.168.1.131.129:1299
```

Is there anything special to do to connect to a remote queue ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, so after trying a lot, I finally found out what the problem was :

I didn't start JBoss on the remote server in a way it could accept remote connections. by default, JBoss starts allowing only local connections.

so, I restarted it with this argument : -b 0.0.0.0 and it works fine now.

Thanks for your help and support.

Answer (score 1):

Have you verified that you can connect to that remote host *and* port, i.e. `telnet 192.168.131.129 1299`?  You might have a firewall that's blocking some traffic but allowing pings.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion. I've tried and couldn't connect. there's no firewall and it still doesn't work.